# Is there a .net Binding for Port Audio with a working example

Tags: c#, .net, webrtc, portaudio

Using apprtc for Windows I want to capture the desktop audio and pass it to the webrtc stream. Has anyone tried this?

So far: [link for .net Bindings](https://github.com/ka2rvo/PortAudio) this project is pretty old  with no documentation. Has anyone used this? A working example would be great.

Comment: Have you tried that project, does it work?

Comment: I tried https://github.com/Kyle-Gagner/PortAudio.Net and it is giving me 'Unable to load DLL 'libportaudio' or one of its dependencies: ALso I stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609432/feeding-input-stream-from-portaudio-to-webrtcaudioprocessing . I am looking for C# implementation of this?

Comment: Regarding the DLL, do you actually have a `portaudio_x86.dll` or `portaudio_x64.dll`

Comment: No I don't I used https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/PortAudioInstall link to generate one. I ran all commands but cannot see any .dll file being generated. If there is link to download let me know.

Comment: @wp78de thank you for your help. Can you answer my next question      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545745/feeding-input-stream-from-portaudio-to-webrtcaudioprocessing-using-c-sharp

Comment: ok. submit your answer I will mark it as answer. I did not intend to do take any credit!

Comment: It's fine. Ultimately, you found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Download https://github.com/loopunit/portaudio and follow this http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html and add the .dll generated as resource file in the Windowsformstest project https://github.com/tlove123/portaudiosharp

and make sure u set the file added as copy always.

Comment: Canonical PortAudio is at https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package [PortAudioSharp2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PortAudioSharp2)

- has bindings for C# (and other dotnet languages)
- includes binary dlls for Mac/Windows/Linux.
- is very well done and stable